# Java: the difference between record-declaration and declaration of object

Tags: java, object

I am just browsing an teaching article about Java and there is this question:

> What's the difference between the declaration of record and
>   declaration of object?

Not sure what does it mean, is there any difference?
(I am not very familiar with JAVA)

Comment: What article? Need context.

Comment: I think you have good reason to be confused. This is extremely vague ad meaningless without _a lot_ more context.

Comment: Could it be talking about pointers? The reference to the object, and the object data itself?

Comment: It's a question for a Java test, just like this.

Comment: 'record' is not a term that has a specific meaning in java, and has too many other meanings in other places to know which one to use here. So those asking for 'context' are correct, because we have to know what is meant by 'record' (and "declaration of record") before we can help.

Answer (score 0):

The term "record" is not used in Java. Basically, record is an object with only fields and no methods. The C structures could be an example of a record. So the following Java class would be a "record":

```
class Record {
    public String field1;
    public int field2;
}
```

This could be called a record, however nobody every uses this term. The example code was the class declaration. To declare and create an object of this class you should use the following:

```
Record record = new Record();
```

This would create an object of type Record and put it to the variable called record.